# How to use regex for replacing html meta tags

Tags: java, regex

I want to read a xhtml document by using an xml parser.
The problem is that the given document is not really valid because it has characters in the content attribute of its meta tags which must be entities:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <title>My page</title>
    <meta name="dc:title" content="This is <my> example" />
    <meta name="dc:publisher" content="A&B" />
  </head>
</html>
```

Now I have the idea to read the content with f.e. the BufferedReader first, look for the meta tags and convert to entities.
Only then I will hand over the "corrected" document to the parser.

But I have some problems to find a possible regular expression to do the work.

Comment: Use jsoup, or similar, **not a regex**: https://jsoup.org/cookbook/modifying-data/set-attributes

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: `replaceAll("<meta .*?/>", "")`. Not very safe, but it works ok. See [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/fI9aZ5/1). --- Of course, a document with `A&B` in an attribute is *not* a valid XHTML document, so maybe the original document should be fixed?

Comment: @Andi: I can't create a valid xhtml document because I'm not the author. I only want to read given documents. Your replacement works but then I'm not be able to find the meta data in the DOM after parsing. Maybe it's better to use only indexOf and substring. It's more code tht's why I looked for a regex solution but I have no better idea. But thanks anyway!